# Contact's child records transfers

Tags: trigger, lookup

I have few custom child objects (lookup relationship) of Contact. My requirement is if I change the Contact owner from User A to User B, I want the child records of that Contact to be transferred to User B. And this transfer is being done by the user with Standard User profile. Kindly suggest. Below is the trigger which I wrote in order to meet the requirement. However its not saving and giving the error-

> "Didn't understand relationship 'ABC__c' in FROM part of query call.
>   If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append
>   the '__r' after the custom relationship name. "

Trigger-

```
trigger OwnerUpdate on Contact(after update) {
try {
Set<Id> contactIds = new Set<Id>(); 
Map<Id, String> oldOwnerIds = new Map<Id, String>(); 
Map<Id, String> newOwnerIds = new Map<Id, String>(); 
ABC__c[] abcUpdates = new ABC__c[0]; 


for (Contact a : Trigger.new) { 
    if (a.OwnerId != Trigger.oldMap.get(a.Id).OwnerId) {
        oldOwnerIds.put(a.Id, Trigger.oldMap.get(a.Id).OwnerId); 
        newOwnerIds.put(a.Id, a.OwnerId); 
        contactIds.add(a.Id); 
    }
}

if (!contactIds.isEmpty()) { 
    for (Contact con : [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM ABC__c) FROM Contact WHERE Id in :contactIds]) { 
        String newOwnerId = newOwnerIds.get(con.Id); 
        String oldOwnerId = oldOwnerIds.get(con.Id); 
        for (ABC__c c : con.ABC__c) { 
            if (c.OwnerId == oldOwnerId) { 
                ABC__c updatedabc = new ABC__c(Id = c.Id, OwnerId = newOwnerId); 
                abcUpdates.add(updatedabc); 
            }
        }

    }
    update abcUpdates; 

}
 } catch(Exception e) { 
System.Debug('OwnerUpdate failure: '+e.getMessage()); 
}
}
```

Comment: Anyway you need to maintain the `OwnerId` of `Contact` as well as those child objects same, is it?

Comment: Yes. I tried the same with code, but its giving me an error. I've updated the same in the question.

Comment: It's because you are not using the correct relationship name in the query. Check the correct one with a WSDL. *Setup > Develop > API > Generate WSDL* in the WSDL under `Contact`, find the correct relationship name for `ABC__c` and use it in the inner query

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I checked for API> Generate WSDL which is actually giving me many options to Generate WSDL. I clicked on "Generate Enterprise WSDL" and did copied the reference (which was appeding __r instead of __c) but it didnt saved the trigger either and gave the same error. Here is the query which I changed.        
"for (Contact con : [SELECT Contact.Id, (SELECT ABC__c.Id, ABC__c.OwnerId FROM Contact.ABC__r) FROM Contact WHERE Id in :contactIds])".
Please help

Comment: Enterprise WSDL is fine. Try this `[SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM ABC__r) FROM Contact WHERE Id in :contactIds];`

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but its still not working. Please suggest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18646/discussion-between-highfive-and-salesforce-learner).

Comment: Another guess to try is Abcs__r (a plural).